# jQuery CSS AddClass - RemoveClass Shifts Divs In Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-9

I have an HTML table and I provide some hover highlight feature using jQuery and CSS. My hover event is like below :

```
$('#' + element.id + ' tr:not(:first,[class="summary_row"])').die('mouseover mouseout').live('mouseover mouseout', function (event) {
            if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
                // do something on mouseover
                $(this).addClass("table_row_hover");
            } else {
                // do something on mouseout
                $(this).removeClass("table_row_hover");
            }
});
```

I simply add and remove a CSS class to corresponding table row when mouse gets over and out of it. My CSS class (table_row_hover) is simple and contains only back color and fore color:

```
.table_row_hover
{
    background-color: #660033;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Under my table div, there is another div that contains a pager to provide pagination feature for table. When I hover on the table rows it shifts this pager div down. Every time I hover, it shifts more. This only happens in Internet Explorer and when the table div has horizontal scroll bar visible.(table div has   attributes   overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -ms-overflow-y: hidden;).

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: you can use hover and toggleClass to reduce length of your code..

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in internet explorer. I can't find a link to a public for this for Internet Explorer. The bug is that when you have a horizontal scrollbar in an element its height increases on addClass/removeClass. Microsoft have also obviously been aware of this issue because it seems to have been resolved in Internet Explorer 10.

Comment: Perhaps point him to some documentation on the bug? Not a terribly useful answer without that is it?

Answer (score 0):

`live()` function is deprecated so do not use it.

```
$('#' + element.id + ' tr:not(:first,[class="summary_row"])').die('mouseover mouseout').on('mouseover mouseout', function (event) {
$(this).toggleClass("table_row_hover");

})
```